# AttributeError with an outer join in pandas 0.15.1

Tags: python, pandas

```
  In [26]:  xyz = temp_val_ns.join(temp_ref_ns, how='outer')

  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-e10ed4b1946b>", line 1, in <module>
    xyz = temp_val_ns.join(temp_ref_ns, how='outer')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3867, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3881, in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 187, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py", line 260, in _get_join_info
    left_ax.join(right_ax, how=self.how, return_indexers=True)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1729, in join
    elif self.is_monotonic and other.is_monotonic:

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 577, in is_monotonic
    return self._engine.is_monotonic_increasing

AttributeError: 'pandas.index.Int64Engine' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic_increasing'
```

I didn't have any problems in 0.15 so it might be related to [this change](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8680).  Just curious if anyone is having similar problems and if there is a workaround for it.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding in a reproducible example.

```
aaa = {'bbot_sampler_ref': {1413180063086001221: True,
1413180063086915835: True,
1413180063086998237: True,
1413180063087746824: True,
1413180063089530483: True},
'bw_ref': {1413180063086001221: 128.04550264550264,
1413180063086915835: 128.04553191489362,
1413180063086998237: 128.04559139784948,
1413180063087746824: 128.04556756756756,
1413180063089530483: 128.04492822966506}}
temp_ref_ns = pd.DataFrame(aaa)
bbb = {
 'agg': {1413180063080171210: 1,
  1413180063080280537: 1,
  1413180063080365279: 1,
  1413180063080440876: 1,
  1413180063080514973: 1},
 'last_trade': {1413180063080171210: 150.75,
  1413180063080280537: 150.75,
  1413180063080365279: 150.75,
  1413180063080440876: 150.75,
  1413180063080514973: 150.75},
 'mid': {1413180063080171210: 150.745,
  1413180063080280537: 150.745,
  1413180063080365279: 150.745,
  1413180063080440876: 150.745,
  1413180063080514973: 150.745},
 'pcap_seq': {1413180063080171210: 17613,
  1413180063080280537: 17615,
  1413180063080365279: 17617,
  1413180063080440876: 17619,
  1413180063080514973: 17621},
 'timestamp': {1413180063080171210: 1413180063080171210,
  1413180063080280537: 1413180063080280537,
  1413180063080365279: 1413180063080365279,
  1413180063080440876: 1413180063080440876,
  1413180063080514973: 1413180063080514973}}
 temp_val_ns = pd.DataFrame(bbb)
```

Then, this will fail with the error above:

```
xyz = temp_val_ns.join(temp_ref_ns, how='outer')
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example? (and for bug reports: better report them at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in 0.15.1. The error you are receiving could be because you updated the source but didn't recompile (if you 'manually' installed the code), as the function that is called `is_monotonic_increasing` is new in 0.15.1.

```
In [11]: temp_ref_ns
Out[11]: 
                    bbot_sampler_ref      bw_ref
1413180063086001221             True  128.045503
1413180063086915835             True  128.045532
1413180063086998237             True  128.045591
1413180063087746824             True  128.045568
1413180063089530483             True  128.044928

In [12]: temp_val_ns
Out[12]: 
                     agg  last_trade      mid  pcap_seq            timestamp
1413180063080171210    1      150.75  150.745     17613  1413180063080171210
1413180063080280537    1      150.75  150.745     17615  1413180063080280537
1413180063080365279    1      150.75  150.745     17617  1413180063080365279
1413180063080440876    1      150.75  150.745     17619  1413180063080440876
1413180063080514973    1      150.75  150.745     17621  1413180063080514973

In [13]: temp_val_ns.join(temp_ref_ns, how='outer')
Out[13]: 
                     agg  last_trade      mid  pcap_seq     timestamp bbot_sampler_ref      bw_ref
1413180063080171210    1      150.75  150.745     17613  1.413180e+18              NaN         NaN
1413180063080280537    1      150.75  150.745     17615  1.413180e+18              NaN         NaN
1413180063080365279    1      150.75  150.745     17617  1.413180e+18              NaN         NaN
1413180063080440876    1      150.75  150.745     17619  1.413180e+18              NaN         NaN
1413180063080514973    1      150.75  150.745     17621  1.413180e+18              NaN         NaN
1413180063086001221  NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN             True  128.045503
1413180063086915835  NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN             True  128.045532
1413180063086998237  NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN             True  128.045591
1413180063087746824  NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN             True  128.045568
1413180063089530483  NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN           NaN             True  128.044928
```

Comment: Good chance you are right.  I'm using Anaconda and I did "conda update pandas" to get 0.15.1.  After I ran into this I tried removing and re-installing pandas which didn't solve it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe you don't have permission or something failed in the install?